# Bad JSON escape sequence

Tags: json.net

I have this JSON string:

```
{"Time":"11/03/2015 05:32:29.273","Message":"Error loading chirps. Cannot create file \U+0022E:\U+005CUsers\U+005Cgwardell\U+005CDocuments\U+005CSRChirp\U+005CPictures\U+0022. Access is denied","Source":"BT","Method":"GetChirpsFromServer.SaveMedia.SaveBitmap","ChirpID":"9851","LogType":"Error","DeviceType":"Win","Action":"RecordLog","UserID":"98000001","DeviceID":"3675"}
```

as near as I can tell it conforms to the RFC 7159 JSON Standard.

This validator tells me it's OK:
http://freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

However, when I run it through this code:

```
public class TAction
{
    public string Action = ""; 
}
...
TAction Params = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TAction>(JSON);
```

I get:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Bad JSON escape sequence: \U. Path 'Message', line 1, position 88.
```

At position 88 is the first escaped quite mark: \U+0022

What is wrong?

Is this a bug in JsonConvert?

Comment: As far as I can tell the `U` should be `u` and the `+` should not be there at all.  See http://json.org/

Comment: It is probably more common to escape a quote as `\"` for that matter.  More compact if nothing else.

Comment: Bob77 is right-- the JSON escape sequence is wong.  It should be `\u0022` not `\U+0022`.  BTW, your JSON does not validate using http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I started going with \u0022 and \" and \n and that was going good.

Then I got another idea and looked more closely at the class I was using on my mobile client and found that TJSONObject (Delphi Object Pascal) had another stringify method besides ToString which doesn't do any escaping. It turns out the ToJSON method does all of the required escaping and is compatible with JsonConvert (in my Asp.net web-service) so I didn't have to do any custom escaping at all.

Thanks for the pointers.  They got me headed in the right direction.